# Duplicate records when loading html table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, html-table, duplicates, records

I want to populate a table using jQuery.  I have an array of strings and when I click a button to run a function, I'd like to use that array to populate the table.  The first time I click the button, it works perfectly, but when I call the function a second time, the rows are duplicated :/  (The table is not reset)

My html code:

```
  <table id="tableIdentity" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
       <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

   <button type="button" onclick="loadTable();">load table</button>
```

My js function:

```
function loadTable() {

   var data = ['allan','ronaldo','damian'];

   for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
       var row = '<tr><td>'+data[i]+'</td></tr>';
       $('#tableIdentity').append(row);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a class and remove it when you click

```
function loadTable() {    
   var data = ['allan','ronaldo','damian'];
   $('#tableIdentity .append_class').remove();
   for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
       var row = '<tr class="append_class"><td>'+data[i]+'</td></tr>';
       $('#tableIdentity').append(row);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call the function multiple times without clearing the added rows first, it will just run append again for each row.  This will add the content as many times as you click the button.  If you prefer it to not do that, you can remove the rows first, for instance:

```
function loadTable() {

   var data = ['allan','ronaldo','damian'];
   $("#tableIdentity tr").remove()
   for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
       var row = '<tr><td>'+data[i]+'</td></tr>';
       $('#tableIdentity').append(row);
   }
}
```

Comment: He said "the first time works perfectly" so i think he want to keep first row